# Spring Cloud sleuth breaking DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've a spring boot app version 1.3.3.RELEASE and I've added Spring Cloud Sleuth get those tracing goodies. After adding spring-cloud-sleuth I see some of my async API's are breaking as passed in `org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor.` is null. Short story, I'm using `org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor` from spring security to pass security context around different executors. For that I'm just wrapping those executors into `org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor` instances during application start up. What I'm not sure is why Spring Sleuth is becoming a problem here. The way we're using async processing is, we have created a custom annotation and then created a point cut's around that to inject async behavior.

Example:

```
public class Async implements AsyncConfigurer {

 public Executor getCustomAsyncExecutor() {

   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   //all configuration for thread pool
   return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
 }

 public Executor getProcessingExecutor() {

   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   //all configuration for thread pool
   return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
 }

}

public class MyControllerClass {

@Autowired
private Executor myProcessingExecutor;

@MyCustomAsyncAnnotation
public ResponseObject getResponse() {
    //As soon as below code get's executed I get NPE as 

    //`org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor.executor` is null. What I'm not sure is why it's null??

    // As you see above in my Async class I've registered executor in DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor, then why it's null here?

//If I remove spring-cloud-sleuth code works fine once again.
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> ..., myProcessingExecutor); 
   }
}

class MyCustomAspect {
private Executor myCustomAsyncExecutor;
//create point cut here for those method which have 
// @MyCustomAsyncAnnotionation and process it async via above executor.
```

}

I'm using spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE, rest easy, spring-security 4.0.3.RELEASE, spring-cloud-sleuth 1.0.12.RELEASE

Comment: @marcin-grzejszczak Do you have pointers on this?

Comment: Have you checked of the problem persists with the latest Camden version? (Note you'll have to bump boot). If it does then it's a bug and please file an issue at github

Comment: And please upload your sample to Github too - that way it will be easier for me to replicate this.